# Why doesn't my sound card start? It reports code 10

Tags: sound-card

When I installed the XP for first time my sound card was working fine. But only after the first reboot it has stopped working.

Under Device Manager, the section "sound video and game controller" the entry YAMAHA Native DS1 WDM Driver, has a exclamation mark on it. On left clicking and selecting properties it shows this message "This device cannot start. (Code 10)".

On trying to update driver it says a better driver can not be found. Any idea how I can solve the issue?

Update: As suggested by harrymc I uninstalled the device "YAMAHA Native DS1 WDM Driver" , and scanned for hardware changes. The windows detected and installed the soundcard and it started working properly.BUT, after restarting the same problem occurs. So, now everytime I reboot the computer I am stuck to, repeating the process of uninstalling the device to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Your driver has become corrupted.

Try first to delete the device in Device Manager, then reboot and see if it is found.

You could also try to find the right driver in the Yamaha [Downloads](http://download.yamaha.com/top/?site=usa.yamaha.com&language=en).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I need to start a new answer because of the bounty</sup>

In my previous answer I suggested downloading the right driver from Yamaha.
Have you had success in finding it?

If not, could you please tell the exact model of your card, so I can search for it. I think that the name "YAMAHA Native DS1 WDM" is only a generic name.

**EDIT**

I was unable to find a driver for this card (the only one I found was for Windows 98SE!).

You should maybe address the question to Yamaha Support (for the US this is [here](http://usa.yamaha.com/support/contact/audio_visual/). Specify well your OS, 32/64-bitness, the above sticker on the card and how Windows identifies it.

If this is a very old card, it may be that Windows XP does not support it very well.

Comment: Here is what is written on the soundcard "YAMAHA XG YMF740B-V 9901 KAIQ". Do you think it is driver problem? I would be grateful if you can find the driver, I am unable to find it on the website you directed me to.

Comment: I have added more info.